# How to sum value of specific keys in an Axios and reactjs Response

Tags: html, reactjs

Hi i m working with react and axios and i want to sum value in reactjs that value i m getting from api. i want to sum TotalVolume, TotalVolume, totalSell and totalBuy from array.

**What i am getting**

```
{
    "TotalTrade": 2,
    "TotalVolume": 200,
    "totalSell": 0,
    "totalBuy": 2
},
{
    "TotalTrade": 2,
    "TotalVolume": 200,
    "totalSell": 1,
    "totalBuy": 1
},
```

**What i am Want**

```
{
    "TotalTrade": 4,
    "TotalVolume": 400,
    "totalSell": 2,
    "totalBuy": 2
},
```

**my Axios code**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
  };

  getData() {
    axios.get(`https://api-test-demo.com/performance/get/all/orders/details/between/dates?page_from=0&page_to=100&date_from=&date_to=`)
      .then(res => {
        const faq = res.data;
        this.setState({ faq });
      })
  };
```

**Showing data here**

```
        {this.state.faq &&
          <div className="faqListC">
            {this.state.faq.map(faqList => (
              <div className="faqList">
                <div className="qNum">Question: <b>{faqList.ClientInv19Id}</b>
                </div>

                <div className="aNum">
                  <span className="ansD">Ans.: </span>
                  <div
                    className="innerF"
                    >
{faqList.ClientBowId}
                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            ))}

          </div>}
```

Comment: This data that you're getting from the API, is it one json object with two objects of TotalTrade or are you getting this data from two different api calls?

Comment: from one api @SampurnG

Comment: Okay so the answer by @adrian won't work then, let me write you a solution for it

Comment: not working please help me @SampurnG

Answer (score 4):

If we say your array is called results, we could use a [reduce array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to add together all the values like below:

```
let resultSum = results.reduce(function(previous, current) {
  return {
    TotalTrade: previous.TotalTrade + current.TotalTrade,
    TotalVolume: previous.TotalVolume + current.TotalVolume,
    totalSell: previous.totalSell + current.totalSell,
    totalBuy: previous.totalBuy + current.totalBuy,

  }
});
```

Comment: where i need to add this code @adrian

Comment: Where ever you get the data back that is not unsummed yet would be my suggestion.

Comment: My array called
[
{
    "TotalTrade": 2,
    "TotalVolume": 200,
    "totalSell": 0,
    "totalBuy": 2
},
{
    "TotalTrade": 2,
    "TotalVolume": 200,
    "totalSell": 1,
    "totalBuy": 1
},]

Comment: i m using  .reduce function first time in my code so i dont understand where i need to add

Comment: So if your array is  [ { "TotalTrade": 2, "TotalVolume": 200, "totalSell": 0, "totalBuy": 2 }, { "TotalTrade": 2, "TotalVolume": 200, "totalSell": 1, "totalBuy": 1 },] is called "myArray" for example, you would use, `myArray.reduce(...`

Answer (score 1):

Okay so basically your API is returning this Array if I'm not wrong

```
[
{
    "TotalTrade": 2,
    "TotalVolume": 200,
    "totalSell": 0,
    "totalBuy": 2
},
{
    "TotalTrade": 2,
    "TotalVolume": 200,
    "totalSell": 1,
    "totalBuy": 1
},
]
```

... and many more objects in this response array

what you'd want to do here is take the array from the response and run it through a loop and add all the values manually. you can create a new state/variable as well depending upon your requirement to update the component.

```
//create anew state variable if you want your component to reload
const [reponseData, setResponseData] = react.useState({
    TotalTrade: 0,
    TotalVolume: 0,
    totalSell: 0,
    totalBuy: 0

})
```

use this in the "Then" call

```
let totalTrade = 0, totalVolume = 0, totalSell = 0, totalBuy = 0; 
let data = response.data;
for(var i=0; i< data.length ; i++) 
{
   totaltrade += data[i].TotalTrade;
   totalVolume += data[i].TotalVolume;
   totalSell += data[i].totalSell;
   totalBuy += data[i].totalBuy;
}

//after computing the actual sum values set the state for the state variable to update the component. 
//your setState method goes here, I've just used a state of my own
setResponseData({...responseData, TotalTrade : totalTrade, TotalVolume : totalVolume, totalSell : totalSell, totalBuy : totalBuy});
```